# Using MATLAB shared library in visual studio c++

Tags: matlab, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I have a m-file in MATLAB.It calulates `normxcorr2` between an image and a template as follow:

```
function norm_res = TMatch(temp,image)
    c = normxcorr2(temp,image);
    norm_res = max(c(:));
```

when I running this m-file from MATLAB command line with two images as image and template, it gives me 0.8076 as a result.
Now I build it as a shared library with following command:

```
mcc -B cpplib:TMatch TMatch.m
```

in MATLAB command line and it generates required files for using in C++.

Now I use generated shared library in visual studio as following:

```
    mclInitializaApplication();
    TMatchInitialize();
    Mat img = imread("image.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat tmp = imread("temp.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    // these files are the same as files which are used in MATLAB

    mwArray mwImg(img.rows,img.cols,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
    mwArray mwTemp(tmp.rows,tmp.cols,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);

    mwArray result;

    mwImg.SetData(img.data,img.cols * img.rows);
    mwTemp.SetData(tmp.data,tmp.cols * tmp.rows);

    TMatch(1,result,mwTemp,mwImg);

    double normed_res;
    result.GetData(&normed_res); //finally result will be 0.198949
```

As you can see when I run m-file in MATLAB result will be:

```
0.8076
```

and when I generate a shared library and use it in visual studio C++ 
the result will be:

```
0.198949
```

please tell me why this happens?
Thanks in advance.
(@Miki  @A.Riazi)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that MATLAB and VC++/OpenCV use different memory management strategies for matrices, where MATLAB is column-major while row-major for VC++/OpenCV.

Try to transpose the matrix in MATLAB or in VC++/OpenCV before calling MATLAB.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your answer @herohuyongtao.  
I add following lines of codes to my VC++ program:
`Mat t_img, t_tmp;
traspose(img,t_img);
traspose(tmp,t_temp);`
and run the previous code except replace "img" and "tmp" with "t_img" and "t_tmp" and run again 
but nothing changed and I recieve previous answer again (0.198949).  
I tried my MATLAB code with following lines:
`temp = transpose(temp);
image = transpose(image);`
and again I do "normxcorr2", in this case again I recieve previous answer (0.8076 ) and nothing changed.  
Can you explain to me if I do something wrong?